# Grails Unit Test fails: String-based queries like [executeQuery] are currently not supported in this implementation of GORM

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm, spock

There are other questions on SO about this, but they are pretty old and none offer solutions to my issue.

I'm getting the following error from a unit test:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: String-based queries like [executeQuery] are currently not supported in this implementation of GORM. Use criteria instead.
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.unsupported(GormStaticApi.groovy:984)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.executeQuery(GormStaticApi.groovy:896)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.executeQuery(GormStaticApi.groovy:892)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.executeQuery(GormEntity.groovy:1026)
at com.mycompany.SomeService.$tt__getSomeThing(SomeService.groovy:54)
at com.mycompany.SomeService.getSomeThing_closure1(SomeService.groovy)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
at com.mycompany.SomeServiceSpec.nominal getSomeThing(SomeServiceSpec.groovy:45)
```

The line that is breaking the test is:

```
def something = SomeDomain.executeQuery("some HQL string")
```

The test looks like this currently (just tracing data currently):

```
    @TestFor(SomeService)
    @Mock(SomeDomain)
    class SomeServiceSpec extends Specification {

        def setup() {
        }

        def cleanup() {
        }

        void "nominal getSomeThing"() {
            setup:
            def args = ['thingId':1l]

            when:
            def something = service.getSomething(args)

            then:
            println "Thing: ${something}"
        }
    }
```

My Setup:

```
Grails 3.1.12
Hibernate 4 (I upgraded to 5 with no change in behavior)
Java 1.8
Groovy 2.4.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `HibernateTestMixin`. It supports string-based HQL queries with Hibernate 4.

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.gorm.Domain
import grails.test.mixin.hibernate.HibernateTestMixin

@TestFor(SomeService)
@Domain(SomeDomain)
@TestMixin(HibernateTestMixin)
class SomeServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "nominal getSomeThing"() {
        setup:
        def args = ['thingId':1l]

        when:
        def something = service.getSomething(args)

        then:
        println "THING: ${something}"
    }
}
```

You will also need to add to your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support'
}
```

Comment: @beechovsky I'm assuming that's the `SomeDomain` class you were referencing?

Comment: Correct. I think I should add this above - that domain is from a different package than the service, com.mycompany.anotherpackage for example. It also has a different dataSource, which I suspect is the problem. I've tried upgrading to Hibernate5 to address that issue to no avail.